# syntax error in the INSERT INTO statement

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio-2012, oledb

I am trying to insert some values in User table, there are 4 attributes in

```
User-User_Name varchar(20)  
User_Password varchar(20)  
Entry_Date timestamp  
Entry_Time timestamp
```

I have tried a lot but I'm not able to find out the problem.

```
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(cs))
{

    string cb1 = "INSERT INTO User([User_Name],[User_Password],[Entry_Date],[Entry_Time]) VALUES (@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4)";

    using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(cb1, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", txtUserName.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val2", txtPassword.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val3", DateTime.Now.ToString("d"));
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val4", DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

Comment: what is your exception  exactly?

Comment: "User" is a reserved word with Access/oldDB

Comment: Try with just `DateTime.Now` - you are now strying to store a string value in a timestamp column

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

User is a reserved keyword in transact sql. Enclose it in square brackets like INSERT INTO [User] ....

Answer (score 0):

`USER` is a [reserved keyword](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266) in OLE DB Provider. You need to use it with square brackets like `[USER]` I know `User` and `USER` are not the same but that means your database server is not case sensitive for this options.

Your `Entry_Date` and `Entry_Time` columns are `timestamp` but you try to add string representations of your `DateTime` parts.

Best way is to change your `Entry_Date` column to `Date` type and provide these columns your current local time with theirs [`.Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`.TimeOfDay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties.

And don't use `AddWithValue` method. [It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.

For the last, do **not** save passwords as a plain text. Read [Best way to store password in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database)

```
using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(cs))
using (var comm = new connection.CreateCommand())
{
    comm.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO [User]([User_Name],[User_Password],[Entry_Date],[Entry_Time]) 
                         VALUES (@val1,@val2,@val3,@val4)"
    comm.Parameters.Add("@val1", txtUserName.Text);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@val2", txtPassword.Text);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@val3", DateTime.Now.Date);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@val4", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);

    connection.Open();
    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot soner, it works.Thank you for the suggestions.. You are the best!!!!!!!!!! :)

Comment: @ArianSajid Glad to help.